# Django - Using 'exclude' to query a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models joined by a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    room = models.ManyToManyField(Room)
```

I'm trying to exclude all Rooms which have an Event that starts before a particular date and ends after a different date.  I can get all rooms which fit this criteria using filter:

```
Room.objects.filter(event__start__lt=date1, event__end__gt=date2)
```

and that works fine, though it returns all the Rooms I want not those I don't.  If however I do exactly the same thing, but replace `filter` with `exclude`:

```
Room.objects.exclude(event__start__lte=date1, event__end__gte=date2)
```

then it excludes more Rooms than it found using filter.  Does anyone know why this is?  I'm currently having to do a bit of a silly workaround, namely:

```
badRooms = Room.objects.filter(event__start__lt=date1, event__end__gt=date2)
badRooms = [x.id for x in badRooms]
return Room.objects.filter(id__in=badRooms)
```

but this is both silly and inefficient, so if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong with `exclude`, that would be much appreciated!

I assume the problem lies in the many-to-many relationship, as I need to remove all Rooms which have at least one single Event fitting both criteria, but not Rooms which have two different events which each fit one of the criteria.

Comment: one possible cause could be that you're doing 'less than' and 'greater than' in both the filter and the exclude query. If you use 'less than or equal' and 'greater than or equal' in ONE of them, do the result match up?

Comment: Read this you get the clear view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#filter

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exclude

Comment: @Hoff: Nope, it's still out I'm afraid.

Comment: If it helps, when there are no `badRooms`, `exclude` works as expected (by not excluding anything), but when there's one `badRooms`, `exclude` removes 43 Rooms instead of one.  If there are eg 34 `badRooms`, `exclude` removes 44 rooms instead of 34.

Comment: have you tried querying with 'Q'? from django.db.models import Q

Comment: your query should be something like this Room.objects.filter(event__start__lt=date1, event__end__gt=date2).exclude('your code to remove badrooms')

Comment: I guess you are trying to avoid two queries. However, you could first filter the events matching your criteria. and then exclude rooms tied to those events (still 2 db hits, though)

Comment: Or try something like this using annotations `Room.objects.filter(event__start__lt=date1, event__end__gt=date2).annotate(event_count=Count('event')).filter(event_count=0)`

Answer (score 0):

The events has the rooms, but the room do not have events

try :

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(start__lt=date1) | Q(end__gt=date2))
```

or:

```
Event.objects.filter(start__lt=date1, end__gt=date2)
```

if you want to filter by end/start the rooms you have to added to the model:

```
class Room(models.Model):
  id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  start = models.DateTimeField()
  end = models.DateTimeField()
```

And then u can filter like this:

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(room__start__lt=date1) | Q(room__end__gt=date2))
```

or:

```
Event.objects.filter(room__start__lt=date1, room__end__gt=date2)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it's a many-to-many relationship, so each room has many events, meaning many start and end times, so we can't add those fields to the Room object.  Also, since it's a many-to-many relationship, the room does indeed have the events, even though it's not explicitly stated in the model.

Comment: Then you have the model wrong, you should have something like this:

    class Room(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, null=True)

   class Event(models.Model):
     start = models.DateTimeField()
     end = models.DateTimeField()

Django add the id's fields for evry model automatically.

Comment: Either way works, that's the point of many-to-many, it goes both ways.  Also, automatically adding id's can be useful but we use these to link to other tables so we set our own.